flutter native splash has an unremovable border
I created a Flutter native splash screen with a PNG image, but it unintentionally displays a splash screen with a green border like the second image below. How can I remove this border? It happens in Android 12 only. There is no border in Android 7.
See the original PNG splash here:
Click here to see image
See the issue here:
Click here to see image
Here is the code in pubspec.yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/splash_screen/splash.png
  android: true
  ios: true

Thank you very much!
I tried to remove splash and add new again, but the border is still there.

Have you tried to give android_12: in pubspec.yaml or flutter_native_splash.yaml file as suggested in flutter_native_splash?

I tried to put android_12: in pubspec file as instructed, but it does not work. The issue is still the same.

Its because the background of the image you are using is not transparent, even though its in png format. Please remove the background of the image and use it.
You can remove the background from the following website https://www.remove.bg/

I don't think so. My PNG image has no background. It's an icon.

Finally, I fixed the issue.
First of all, I put the configuration for Android 12 as suggested here flutter_native_splash
then I change this file content C:\Users\trong\Desktop\evdictionary\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background. Change the color code from green to white as follows:
<vector
android:height="108dp"
android:width="108dp"
android:viewportHeight="108"
android:viewportWidth="108"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:pathData="M0,0h108v108h-108z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M9,0L9,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,0L19,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M29,0L29,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M39,0L39,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M49,0L49,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M59,0L59,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M69,0L69,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M79,0L79,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M89,0L89,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M99,0L99,108"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,9L108,9"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,19L108,19"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,29L108,29"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,39L108,39"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,49L108,49"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,59L108,59"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,69L108,69"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,79L108,79"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,89L108,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,99L108,99"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,29L89,29"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,39L89,39"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,49L89,49"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,59L89,59"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,69L89,69"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,79L89,79"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M29,19L29,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M39,19L39,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M49,19L49,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M59,19L59,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M69,19L69,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M79,19L79,89"
      android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>

